# What's quota_info.datastores in the Dropbox API?

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I'm getting the account information from the Dropbox API. Their [docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info) mention three values about `quota_info` but the API is returning 4:

```
'quota_info': {'quota': 2684354560, 'normal': 1657874, 'datastores': 0, 'shared': 162730881}
```

What's the `datastores` value for? Should I take it into account for anything?

Comment: I'm tagging this as `python`, but it's probably language-independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for the deprecated Datastore API, and the value should now always be zero. (It's kept in to avoid breaking clients that expect it.) So you can ignore it!